# Creating an SQL average for multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, charts, sum, average

I have two tables I need to create an average sum from...

*Caravan Category M:1 Caravan* (caravan has one category, category has many caravans)

Caravan (**Caravan_no**, Rental_amount, annual_rent....

Caravan Category (**Caravan_type_id**, caravan_type, pets ....

Caravan Category type has such entities as; American Classic, Conventional Twin GRP...

I want to create a chart that lists the average rental_amount per caravan type (caravan_type is a static list of choices)

Any helpers??

Comment: Mhat exactly is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Take a look at the SQL AVG() Function here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp and give us more information regarding the exact problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to join the Caravan and Caravan Category tables, and then find the averages grouped by caravan type, e.g. like this:

```
SELECT cat.caravan_type,  AVG(Rental_amount) 
FROM Caravan c
INNER JOIN Category cat
ON c.caravan_type_id = cat.caravan_type_id
GROUP BY cat.caravan_type
```

Comment: Depending on the precise requirements, an outer join might be more appropriate so that the report includes categories which aren't used.

Comment: I have tried your solution but I still can't get it to work... I just want to be able to provide a list that says: american classic, = average cost = £250.00 for intsance. which is a figure that has added all the numerical values in the rental_caravan table and made an average and then joined to the appropriate car_type

Comment: What happens? I.e. what is the symptoms of _can't get it to work_?

Comment: I have got it working now,it was my fault.. Using wrong alliases